# how does URL other than www work

Tags: url

I don't know how to ask this question, so please bear with me.
Sometimes I have seen URLs like 
mail.yahoo.com
image.craislist.com

How does this work? 
What keyword should I put on Google to find some tutorial on this?

Comment: Try googling for "domain name system"

Comment: You might want to google DNS (Domain Name System) for an explanation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called subdomains. Have a look here for more information on them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Answer (score 1):

when you purchase a domain, such as `your-domain.com`, anything before the domain is called a subdomain. you can set these on your domain registrar's management panel.

i.e. `mail.your-domain.com`, `mail` is the subdomain of the domain `your-domain.com`

commonly, websites have `www` as a subdomain of their main domain to enable `www.your-domain.com` as well

if you want to find out more about domains, you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name, http://google.com/search?q=domains, http://google.com/search?q=how+do+domains+work